# Get a function's name, which includes the object that holds it

Tags: javascript

If I have this code

```
var obj = {
    method: function() {
        //do something
    },
}
```

How do I get the function's name? If I access obj.func.name it only gives me "func", when I want "obj.func". How do I get "obj.func"?

Doing it without jQuery is preferred.

Comment: Your function is called `method`. Basically is the name of the property

Comment: There is nothing named `func` anywhere in your code. From what context do you want to get the function's name?

Comment: console.log(Object.keys(obj)[0]);  // output: "method"

Comment: Where do you want to know it?   From inside the method?   If so, it's a bad code smell for any method to know the name of the object that's containing it, because those names are changeable, and it also prevents re-use of that object.

Comment: 'obj.func.name it only gives me "func"' - no, it doesn't. `obj.method.name` gives "method", `obj.func.name` gives a TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. The function doesn't know anything about the object that contains it, or even that the name exists.

Also, what happens if you do this:

```
var foo = obj;
```

What name should you get? obj or foo?

What are you actually trying to do? What do you want to use the name for? There are probably other ways to do what you actually want to accomplish.

Answer (score -1):

So you're trying to reference an object property by a function name?

```js
var obj = {
  func: function method(){
    console.log(this.func.name);
  }
};

obj.func(); // <- like this!
```

So if we want to acess the `obj.func` property  and its function name we can access it via:

```
obj.func.name // <- returns 'method'
```